# When switching themes in blocks, theme stays the same

Tags: 6, blocks, theming

I'm trying to add a block to a specific theme (garland), but no matter what theme I switch to, I'm always shown the admin theme.

If I only have a single theme (garland) enabled, I can access the blocks I need, but there has to be a reason for this.

Edit: Discovered that this is being caused by the module "RealName" I have no idea where to look for the culprit though. Any suggestions?

Edit2: Found [this explanation](http://drupal.org/node/467492), but no real fix. Suggestions?

Comment: What are the modules installed and enabled?

Comment: I have seen this behavior happen with the switchtheme module. Do you have that one installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using hefox's (from Drupal comments) fix

```
<?php
function realname_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
    global $theme;
  if (!$theme) return; // prevent realname from overiding theme on block pages
?>
```

I did add in my own code as a safeguard, in the if statement, the condition that we were on the blocks page.